# a dialog box, and when ok button is clicked it should return 0 and if cancel button is clicked then it should return 1

Tags: android

```
public class DisplayAlert  implements OnClickListener
{
     int   j,t;


    @Override
    public void  onClick(View arg0) 
    {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void funval(int a)
    {
        j=a;

    }
    public int dis1(Context alertCall, String phoneNumber) {

        final ReturnValue ob=new ReturnValue();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new AlertDialog.Builder(alertCall).setTitle("SEND MESSAGE")
           .setMessage("Are you sure you want to send this msg to no ?   "+ phoneNumber)
 .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void  onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
         { 
                     j=0;
                     ob.funval(j);


           }
         })
     .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

               j=1;
              ob.funval(j);

        }
})
.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
.show();
        return j;           
    }


}
```

**I have created this class to display a dialog box, and when ok button is clicked it should return 0 and if cancel button is clicked then it should return 1. But when I call this function from my project it dose not wait for the ok or cancel button to be clicked but returned the initial value of j **

```
final ReturnValue ob1=new ReturnValue();
     DisplayAlert ob = new DisplayAlert();      
     j= ob.dis1(c, phoneNumber);
```

Comment: Indeed. That is normal behavior. You have to rethink. After the .show() no further code. In the onClick handlers you continu your code by calling a function with a parameter which is 0 or 1.

Comment: can  you please suggest  what changes I have to make,

Comment: How can I return the 0 or 1 value based on the user selection from the above function

Comment: You cannot return them. You have to continue with them.

Answer (score 0):

Put the dialog code after `final ResturnVale ob=new ReturnValue()` in its own method. Also, add the `create()` line. Then just call `myDialog()`. Don't forget to `@Override` the onClick's.

```
public void Dialog myDialog() {
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(alertCall);
       builder.setTitle("SEND MESSAGE")
       .setMessage("Are you sure you want to send this msg to no ?   "+ phoneNumber)
       .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void  onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                 j=0;
                 ob.funval(j);
           }
      })
      .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
               j=1;
               ob.funval(j);

           }
      })
      .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
      .show();

      AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
      return dialog;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but its not working, I can't understand your suggestion can you please explain